# MacBook Pro randomly waking up from sleep after Catalina update

Tags: sleep-wake, power-management, catalina

Since the upgrade to macOS Catalina 10.15.0, I've noticed that my MacBook Pro is randomly waking up from sleep.

I use the MBP connected to an External display, BT mouse (MX Master), an external keyboard and the company ethernet through a third-party USB-C docking station.

[Here the output of](https://pastebin.com/raw/prV9Tq7V) `pmset -g log`

At 12:01 I stopped the MBP and closed the lid, and apparently at 12:34 it woke up. Can anyone address the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this report about [com.apple.parsec-fbf.flush process](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/342000-parsec-fbf-agent-prevents-idle-sleep-automatic-on-macos-catalina-10152/) maybe it solves your problem, i'm trying this now because i see a bunch of log for this:

```
2020-01-12 20:33:04 +0100 Assertions            PID 681(UserEventAgent) Summary BackgroundTask "com.apple.parsec-fbf.flush" 249:47:21 id:0x0xb0000856b [System: BGTask kCPU]
2020-01-12 20:48:04 +0100 Assertions            PID 681(UserEventAgent) Summary BackgroundTask "com.apple.parsec-fbf.flush" 250:02:21 id:0x0xb0000856b [System: BGTask kCPU]
2020-01-12 21:03:04 +0100 Assertions            PID 681(UserEventAgent) Summary BackgroundTask "com.apple.parsec-fbf.flush" 250:17:21 id:0x0xb0000856b [System: BGTask kCPU]
2020-01-12 21:18:04 +0100 Assertions            PID 681(UserEventAgent) Summary BackgroundTask "com.apple.parsec-fbf.flush" 250:32:21 id:0x0xb0000856b [System: BGTask kCPU]
2020-01-12 21:33:04 +0100 Assertions            PID 681(UserEventAgent) Summary BackgroundTask "com.apple.parsec-fbf.flush" 250:47:21 id:0x0xb0000856b [System: BGTask kCPU]
2020-01-12 21:48:04 +0100 Assertions            PID 681(UserEventAgent) Summary BackgroundTask "com.apple.parsec-fbf.flush" 251:02:21 id:0x0xb0000856b [System: BGTask kCPU]
2020-01-12 22:03:04 +0100 Assertions            PID 681(UserEventAgent) Summary BackgroundTask "com.apple.parsec-fbf.flush" 251:17:21 id:0x0xb0000856b [System: BGTask kCPU]
2020-01-12 22:18:04 +0100 Assertions            PID 681(UserEventAgent) Summary BackgroundTask "com.apple.parsec-fbf.flush" 251:32:21 id:0x0xb0000856b [System: BGTask kCPU]
```

Quote from the original site

> It's unknown what exactly causes this issue. Somehow parsec-fbf agent
>   goes into state where it prevents comp to go into Idle Sleep. Probably
>   the latest version of parsec-fbf agent introduced in macOS 10.15.2 has
>   some kind of bug which resets idle timer. As macOS kernel uses new
>   version of XNU (6153.61.1), this might be somehow related to both,
>   parsec-fbf agent and kernel.

How to check sleep log?

```
pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  "
```

Current solution (or disable Siri)

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.parsec-fbf.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

After Catalina updated itself to 10.15.1 just yesterday, my iMac has slept through the night like a baby.... Hope it would be the same coming night.

**[edit]**

Didn't worked next night. Still waking up more then once an hour. Looks like it works once after a proper reboot, but then gets into some state where it wakes up more then once an hour. I have an external Monitor which wakes up too and brightens the bedroom with "not connected" message. Also, I can hear annoyingly loud 3T fusion hard drive of iMac.

I will try to reboot tonight and see if it would help the problem. Will report here.

**[more research]**

My iMac is configured to go to sleep at 10:00pm every day in Properties > Energy Saver > Schedule.

According to `pmset -g log` report, the first night (when it worked) it has the following message right before it goes to sleep:

```
2019-10-30 22:10:29 +1100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep': Using AC (Charge:0%) 29966 secs
```

And this is the same line for the next night where it didn't sleep through the entire night and were waking up periodically (It is configured to be allowed to sleep when the display is off, and the display goes off after 15 minutes idle.):

```
2019-10-31 22:10:29 +1100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Software Sleep pid=205': Using AC (Charge:0%) 1599 secs
```

Note that pid=205 is the `loginwindow` process running in user space.

Note the sec value at the end of the log record. 29966 secs equates to 08:19:26, and 1599 secs is 00:26:39. So it makes sense. The second time it went for a shorter sleep despite my Schedule setting.

So it looks like between the fresh boot up state and the following (after wake up) state, there has some hand over of duties happened, and the other system failed to set up the sleep parameters the same way.

Note that on Energy Saver screen I have only 'Put hard disks to sleep when possible' checked, the other options like 'Enable Power Nap', 'Wake for network access' and 'Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off' are all OFF.